# Can only two persons, male & female perform nikah without the helpof imam, vali & witness?

Tags: nikah, sunni

Can only two persons, male & female perform nikah without the help of imam, wali & witness?
And, who can make khutba for personal nikah ?

Comment: What do you mean by khutba? Imam/wali and witnesses are not a help for nikah but conditions to make it lawful.

Answer (score 1):

[Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1319540) and [Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/12/38) narrate:

> the Messenger of Allah said: “Any woman whose marriage is not arranged by her guardian, her marriage is invalid, her marriage is invalid, her marriage is invalid. If (the man) has had intercourse with her, then the Mahr belongs to her in return for his intimacy with her. And if there is any dispute then the ruler is the guardian of the one who does not have a guardian.”
>   حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو بَكْرِ بْنُ أَبِي شَيْبَةَ، حَدَّثَنَا مُعَاذُ بْنُ مُعَاذٍ، حَدَّثَنَا ابْنُ جُرَيْجٍ، عَنْ سُلَيْمَانَ بْنِ مُوسَى، عَنِ الزُّهْرِيِّ، عَنْ عُرْوَةَ، عَنْ عَائِشَةَ، قَالَتْ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ ‏ "‏ أَيُّمَا امْرَأَةٍ لَمْ يُنْكِحْهَا الْوَلِيُّ فَنِكَاحُهَا بَاطِلٌ فَنِكَاحُهَا بَاطِلٌ فَنِكَاحُهَا بَاطِلٌ فَإِنْ أَصَابَهَا فَلَهَا مَهْرُهَا بِمَا أَصَابَ مِنْهَا فَإِنِ اشْتَجَرُوا فَالسُّلْطَانُ وَلِيُّ مَنْ لاَ وَلِيَّ لَهُ"
>
> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: The marriage of a woman who marries without the consent of her guardians is void. (He said these words) three times. If there is cohabitation, she gets her dower for the intercourse her husband has had. If there is a dispute, the sultan (man in authority) is the guardian of one who has none.
>   حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ كَثِيرٍ، أَخْبَرَنَا سُفْيَانُ، أَخْبَرَنَا ابْنُ جُرَيْجٍ، عَنْ سُلَيْمَانَ بْنِ مُوسَى، عَنِ الزُّهْرِيِّ، عَنْ عُرْوَةَ، عَنْ عَائِشَةَ، قَالَتْ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏"‏ أَيُّمَا امْرَأَةٍ نَكَحَتْ بِغَيْرِ إِذْنِ مَوَالِيهَا فَنِكَاحُهَا بَاطِلٌ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ ثَلاَثَ مَرَّاتٍ ‏"‏ فَإِنْ دَخَلَ بِهَا فَالْمَهْرُ لَهَا بِمَا أَصَابَ مِنْهَا فَإِنْ تَشَاجَرُوا فَالسُّلْطَانُ وَلِيُّ مَنْ لاَ وَلِيَّ لَهُ ‏"‏ ‏.‏